# Switch axes and handedness of a quaternion?

Tags: c#, rotation, xna, game-engine, quaternions

I have a quaternion, coming from a system with the following:

```
Right handed.
Forward direction: Y axis
Right direction: X axis
Up direction: Z axis
```

I need to convert this into a coordinate system that is:

```
left-handed.
Forward direction: X axis
Right direction: Y axis
Up direction: Z axis
```

I have tried negating the axis, and angle, I have tried switching values, i cannot get this to work. All help greatly appreciated! I am working in C#, with

```
Microsoft.Xna.Quaternion.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quaternion is a structure of four values `(w, x, y, z)`. If it represents a rotation, then `w = cos(phi/2)` (`phi` being the rotation angle) and `(x, y, z) = sin(phi/2) * (ax, ay, az)` (`(ax, ay, az)` being the rotation axis).

In order to convert the quaternion to another system, it is sufficient to transform the rotation axis. For your example, the transform is:

```
    / 0  1  0 \
T = | 1  0  0 |
    \ 0  0  1 /
```

Finally, since you are changing handedness, you must invert the quaternion or it will rotate in the wrong direction. Summarizing, the transformed quaternion is:

```
(w*, x*, y*, z*) = (w, -y, -x, -z)
```

In general:

```
(x*, y*, z*) = det(T) T (x, y, z) //Assuming column vectors
```